# toString method of a class

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I have a card class that looks like this:

```
public class Card
{
    //instance variables
    private String faceValue; //the face value of the card
    private String suit; //the suit of the card
    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Card()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                faceValue = ranks[i];
                suit = suits[j];
            }
        }
    }

    //getters
    /**
     * Getter for faceValue.
     */
    public String getFaceValue()
    {
        return faceValue;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for suit.
     */
    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    //end of getters

    //methods
    /**
     * This method returns a String representation of a Card object.
     * 
     * @param   none
     * @return  String 
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Dealed a card: " + faceValue + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

And another Deck class that uses the Card class to create an array:

```
public class Deck
{
    //instance variables
    private Card[] deck;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Deck
     */
    public Deck() 
    {
        deck = new Card[52];
    }

    /**
     * String representation.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Dealed a card: " + deck.getFaceValue() + " of " + deck.getSuit();
    }
}
```

My toString method is giving me the error "cannot find symbol - method getFaceValue()". Same for getSuit(). Any ideas why?

Comment: `deck` is a `Card` array, not a `Card`. Arrays don't have those two methods.

Comment: Arrays don't have methods. Elements of arrays have methods.

Comment: You could simply return `Arrays.toString(deck)`, that will give a list of all the card's strings.

Comment: Throw out Deck's toString because even if you got it to work, it's wrong. You might want to show **all** the cards in the deck with a for loop (or not, depending on what your needs are.

Comment: You can only call methods which exist and an array has none (other than those it inherits from `Object`)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but a card's `toString` shouldn't include anything about it being dealt--it just be a human representation of the card. What's being done to/been done with a card is a separate concern.

Comment: What is the purpose of the nested do-loops in the Card constructor? You do realize that the result for any call to `new Card()` will generate a card that is the King of Spades, don't you?

Comment: The loop in your `Card` constructor merely assigns `"King"` to `faceValue` and `"Spades"` to `suit`. So `getFaceValue()` and `getSuit()` will always return those same values, respectively. For every `Card` instance. As @FredK said, but I didn't see that until my screen refreshed.

Comment: "Dealed" is not an English word. You want "dealt". Except for what @DaveNewton said - you shouldn't be dealing with "dealt" in `Card`.

Comment: @LewBloch Oh, oops. That class was initially used to deal out 20 random cards, I forgot to change it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @LewBloch Should I be adding the loops to the Deck's constructor instead?

Comment: The loop as written will be useless no matter where it is because the values are never assigned to separate `Card` instances. You should define `Rank` and `Suit` as `enum`s and construct each `Card` with a `public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`deck` is an array of `Card[] deck`. Hence, you can't call the method getFaceValue() nor getSuit() on it, because those 2 methods are part of the Card class and NOT of the array of Cards.

Answer (score 0):

here some possible solutions to your problem as suggested:

```
public String toString()
{
    return Arrays.toString(deck);
}
```

or for loop through the entire deck

```
public String toString()
{
    String deckInStringForm = "[ ";
    for(int indexOfCard = 0; indexOfCard < deck.length; indexOfCard++)
    {
        deckInStringForm += deck[indexOfCard] + " ";
    }
    deckInStringForm += "]";

    return deckInStringForm;
}
```

or change/add a function to take an index like so

```
public String toString(int index)
{
   return "Card " + index + ": " + deck[index].toString();
}
```